# Do pure java jdbc drivers (Type 4 ) call native database API functions such as OCI and DB2/CLI?

Tags: java, jdbc

Do pure java jdbc drivers (Type 4 ) call native database API functions such as OCI and DB2/CLI?
If not do databases expose custom API for Java programs?
For example reading this intro to OCI here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/index.html
They do not mention thin jdbc driver as being one of the interfaces that use OCI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oracle "thin" driver (Type 4) talks directly to the Oracle database server without any layer in between. It does not even need any Oracle client installation which would provide the OCI API.

Oracle's driver *can* use OCI for certain features (mainly TAF - Transparent Application Failover), but the JDBC URL will look differently then. If that is used, it is no longer a Type 4 driver and requires an Oracle client install (OCI) to be available.

I don't know about the DB2 driver.

Comment: I understand that the thin driver does not need a client installation but what kind of API does Oracle expose to a jdbc client at the server level? On that page they say even the Oracle kernel calls OCI for some operations, why would a java client be an exception

Comment: My understanding is that the thin driver uses a "low-level" wire protocol to talk to the server (basically the same protocol that an OCI API call would use)